# Creating new theme translate.csv files but with a different naming convention

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I am on magento 1.9.
So if I understand magento, you add **theme** translations to app/design/frontend/{site}/{theme}/locale/{locale}/translate.csv. My translate CSV has over several thousand lines which is quite unmanageable. When I try to add new translate csv with a different name it doesn't work. I.E. translate-two.csv.

Does anyone understand how to add a second one or how to better handle these large translate.csv files?